# Overloading not behaving as expected

Tags: java, class, casting, overloading, compareto

I am making a Hotel where my clients are stored in a tree structure so they can be easily searched.

I have two `compareTo` methods for my `Client` class. One to compare the `Client` to another `Client`, and one to compare it to an `int`. `Client` should be of the type `Comparable` because it's inside a tree structure that implements `Comparable`.

```java
//compare Client to int
public int compareTo(int arg0) {
    int result = this.clientId.compareTo(arg0);
    return result;
}

//compare Client to object
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return (this.clientId).compareTo(((Client)o).clientId);
}
```

But it does not have the desired effect. Every time this function gets called, it uses the `compareTo(Object)` method and returns an error that my `int` can't be cast to `Client`. I suppose this is because `Object` is a superclass of `int`(?) but don't quite know how to fix it. I tried working around the problem but can not seem to fix it without changing my entire code.

Comment: Where is the code with the problem?

Comment: As @akuzminykh says, there's nothing intrinsically wrong with the code you've shown. We need to see how you're trying to use it -- that's where the problem is going to lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` use the `compareTo(T)` method (i.e., for raw types like you seem to be using, `compareTo(Object)`, so your overloaded method is just ignored.

While you can, of course, overload the `compareTo` method, you can't force Java's data structures to use it.

One possible approach could be to have the `compareTo(Object)` method check the type dynamically:

```java
//compare Client to object
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Integer toCompare;
    if (o instanceof Client) {
        toCompare = ((Client) o).clientId;
    } else if (o instanceof Integer) {
        toCompare = (Integer) o;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    return (this.clientId).compareTo(toCompare);
}
```